# expo build error EACCES: permission denie

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a managed expo application. It is working fine. but when ever I try to create a a release build I am getting these issue.

```
EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/var/folders/kc/tcj3gswx2375d58ns86504400000gn/T/eas-cli-nodejs/f77fa97c-73a2-4eb2-bdf0-ad473a6170cf-shallow-clone/Library/Mobile Documents/.DS_Store'
```

I have tried to delete folders . delete the project. create a new expo app and tried to build that but every time I have same issue.

some time it is like this. EACCESS: permission denied mkidr '/path/to/file'

I also tried it with sudo . but it has socket issue.

commands I have tried

```
eas build -p android --profile preview
npx eas build -p android --profile preview
sudo npx eas build -p android --profile preview
eas build -p android --profile preview --local
sudo npx eas build -p android --profile preview --local
npx eas build -p android --profile preview --local
```

Comment: What command are you running that leads to that error?  Is this a local build or an EAS Build cloud build?

Comment: I have added commands

Comment: same commands working on the other system. on both systems have clone project

Comment: Are you trying to do a cloud build or a local build?
Are you in Managed Workflow, or do you have an "ios" folder at the root of your project?

Have you tried running `npx expo-doctor` to see if it highlights any problems?